# Получить количество совпадений AutoComleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Имею `AutoCompleteTextView`. Хочу изменить цвет текста, если нет совпадений. Как узнать количество отображенных айтемов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто:

```
autoET.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doWork(autoAdapter.getCount());
    }
}, 80);
```